# Solutions of $-y''-\lambda y=0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the problem
$$
\begin{cases}
-y''-\lambda y=0 \\
y(0)=y(L) \tag{1}
\end{cases}
$$
where, $L>0$ is fixed.

**Question.** It's possible to find a solution $y$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$  satisfying ($1$)?

I thought about is applying second-order linear ODE resolution methods. But I was not successful, because in that case it would depend on the "constant" $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

Moreover, roughly speaking, can the problem ($ 1 $) be interpreted as a eigenvalue problem?

Comment: What is the source of the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ODE $-y''-\lambda y = 0$ corresponds to $y'' + \lambda y = 0$.

If $\lambda < 0$, the general solution of $y'' + \lambda y = 0$ is

$$y(x) = A e^{-\alpha x} + B e^{\alpha x}, $$

where $\alpha = \sqrt{-\lambda}.$

The boundary condition reads as:

$$y(0) = A + B = y(L) = A e^{-\alpha L} + B e^{\alpha L}.$$

A possible way to solve this is the following:

$$A(1 - e^{-\alpha L}) = B(e^{\alpha L} - 1)\Rightarrow$$

$$A = B \frac{e^{\alpha L} - 1}{1 - e^{-\alpha L}}\Rightarrow$$

$$A = B \frac{e^{\alpha L} - 1}{e^{-\alpha L}(e^{\alpha L} - 1)} \Rightarrow$$

$$A = Be^{\alpha L}.$$

If $\lambda > 0$, the general solution of $y'' + \lambda y = 0$ is:

$$y(t) = A \cos (\omega x) + B \sin (\omega x),$$

where $\omega = \sqrt{\lambda}.$

The boundary condition reads as:

$$y(0) = A = y(L) = A \cos (\omega L) + B \sin (\omega L).$$

A  possible way to solve this is the following:

$$A(1 - \cos(\omega L)) = B \sin(\omega L) \Rightarrow$$

$$A = B \frac{\sin(\omega L)}{1 - \cos(\omega L)} \Rightarrow$$

$$A = B \frac{2\sin\left(\frac{\omega L}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\omega L}{2}\right)}{1 - \left(2\cos^2\left(\frac{\omega L}{2}\right)-1\right)} \Rightarrow$$

$$A = B \frac{2\sin\left(\frac{\omega L}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\omega L}{2}\right)}{2\left(1 - \cos^2\left(\frac{\omega L}{2}\right)\right)} \Rightarrow$$

$$A = B \frac{\sin\left(\frac{\omega L}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\omega L}{2}\right)}{\sin^2\left(\frac{\omega L}{2}\right)} \Rightarrow$$

$$A = B \cot\left(\frac{\omega L}{2}\right).$$

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in $ (1) $. I forgot a minus sign.I fixed it.

Comment: The analysis is the same except that insteaf of $\lambda$, you just use $-\lambda$ everywhere.

Comment: But the general solution is not $y(x)=A+B\cdot e^{-\lambda x}$? Since the roots of the characteristic equation $-m^2-\lambda m=0$ are $m_1=0$ and $m_2= -\lambda$.

Comment: The characteristic equation is $-m^2 - \lambda = 0$. There is no first derivative, so no first order term.

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno The answer has been fixed accounting for the change of sign.

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno a better expression for $A$ has been reported for the first case